conditional 0 vs condtioanl 3 which one is better in this context?
"In the 17th century, European merchants didn't transport spices and tea through West Asia anymore due to the influence of the Ottoman Empire there. If European merchants crossed the borders, they were asked to pay huge amounts of money in taxes."
Does this sentence in bold work fine here or should I use a conditional 3 here instead because the route was no longer used, making the statement counter-fact?

Proofreading is Off Topic. You must point out some specific feature of the text being queried, and tell us why you think it might not be valid and/or idiomatic and/or accurately convey the intended meaning.

If you believe that they never did cross borders, you may consider would have been asked to be more appropriate.

Conversely, if you believe at least some merchants took that route, you may consider would be asked to be more appropriate. But there's also If European merchants did cross the borders and If European merchants were to cross / to have crossed the borders, and probably other variations. The question should not be answered until my first comment is addressed.

Do you mean  past conditional? Why would you need that?

@FumbleFingers Maybe I should revise the context:
"In the 17th century, very few European merchants still transported spices and tea through West Asia due to the influence of the Ottoman Empire there. If European merchants crossed the borders, they were asked to pay huge amounts of money in taxes." Does the last sentence sound better in this context?

They're all fine. Choose whichever you like best, bearing in mind that your version (the same in both the question and immediately-preceding comment) is the most "neutral" one compared to the "none at all / only a few" implications of Kate's and my would have been / would be suggestions. But like I said, there's also If European merchants did cross the borders and If European merchants were to cross / to have crossed the borders, and probably other variations. I don't understand why you're having a problem here. You don't need to know/use all possibilities. Yours is fine.
